# Como validar alguns campos em SQL

Tags: php, sql

Tenho o seguinte SQL

```
$contarperfilclienteinsuficiente = "0";
$sqlxmlperfilclienteinsuficiente = "select 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
  COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
from 
  clientes 
where 
  cliente = '$cliente' 
  AND status = '2' 
  AND (disponibilidade <> '0'  OR vanual <> '0' OR vtemporada <> '0')";
$rsqlxmlperfilclienteinsuficiente = mysql_query($sqlxmlperfilclienteinsuficiente)
or die ("Banco XML não abre!");
while($rowxmlperfilclienteinsuficiente = mysql_fetch_array($rsqlxmlperfilclienteinsuficiente))
   {
   $contarperfilclienteinsuficiente = $contarperfilclienteinsuficiente + 1;
   }
```

Preciso que ele conte quantos clientes possuem o **TIPO = 0** e que também tenham os campos **disponibilidade** E **vanual** E **vtemporada** também **zero**

**Importante!** Sempre o campo **TIPO é primordial que seja ZERO** para exibir um registro, mas se o campo **TIPO** for DIFERENTE DE ZERO **E** pelo menos um dos campos **disponibilidade** OU **vanual** OU **vtemporada** estiverem diferentes de **ZERO**, NÃO PODERÁ SER exibido algum registro como resultado.

**Tenho este outro SQL que também não funciona:**

```
    "select
id,disponibilidade,tipo 
from clientes 
where cliente = '$cliente' AND status = '2' AND tipo = '0' AND (disponibilidade <> '0'  OR vanual <> '0' OR vtemporada <> '0')"
```

Me ajudem por favor!

Veja o modelo implementado!

```
$sqlxmlperfilclienteinsuficiente = "SELECT
    COUNT(1) as TOTAL_CLIENTES 
FROM 
    CLIENTES 
WHERE 
    status = 2 
    AND 
    ( 
      ( tipo = 0     
        AND disponibilidade = 0 
        AND vanual = 0 
        AND vtemporada = 0 
      )
      OR
      ( tipo <> 0
        AND (disponibilidade <> 0 OR vanual <> 0 OR vtemporada <> 0)
      )
    )";
$rsqlxmlperfilclienteinsuficiente = mysql_query($sqlxmlperfilclienteinsuficiente)
or die ("Banco XML não abre!");
$num_rowsclienteinsuficiente = mysql_num_rows($rsqlxmlperfilclienteinsuficiente);
```

Comment: A consulta é para retornar o total de clientes, certo? Mas observei que você passa um cliente ( $cliente), o que restringiria o universo somente a este cliente.

Comment: isso mesmo!!!!! Me de uma ajuda na reestruturação deste segundo SQL que postei.

Comment: Tá, então você quer retornar o total de clientes, onde o tipo seja igual a zero e que a disponibilidade, o vanual e o vtemporada não podem ser diferentes de zero, é isso mesmo?

Fiquei na dúvida em relação a esses campos (disponibilidade, vanual e vtemporada)

Comment: @MárcioLordelo Tem retornar registro se o campo tipo for igual a zero e se todos os campos disponibilidade, vanual e vtemporada forem zero. Mas... não retornara registro se o capo tipo for diferente de zero e também se algum dos campos disponibilidade, vanual e vtemporada forem diferentes de zero.

Comment: Em vez de fazer mais de uma postagem com o mesmo problema, você pode [editar a postagem já existente](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/118275/edit) e acrescentar os detalhes que faltaram para uma solução adequada. O ideal mesmo é já fazer a postagem inicial com o máximo de detalhes.

Answer (score -2):

Depois de conversar, pelos chat, vi que o que você quer na verdade é:
Se o `tipo` for zero, já contabiliza. Caso o `tipo` seja diferente de zero, verifica se as outras informações são zero, e contabiliza.

Sendo isso mesmo o que você precisa, creio que a consulta a seguir retorne o esperado:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) as TOTAL_CLIENTES /*Conte 1 exibindo coluna como TOTAL_CLIENTES*/ 
    FROM 
    clientes /*Da tabela de clientes*/ 
    WHERE 
    (tipo = 0 ) /* Se o tipo for zero (só ai o cadastro já está incompleto)*/
    OR (/*OU*/
        tipo <> 0 /*Existe um tipo informado*/
        AND disponibilidade = 0 /*E a disponibilidade é zero*/
        AND vvenda = 0 /* E o vvenda é zero também*/
        AND vtemporada = 0 /* E o vtemporada também é zero, caracterizando um cliente que tem um tipo mas não tem nenhuma informação de valores*/
    )
```

Alterei a postagem em função do que discutimos no chat.

Comment: Não é bem isso! Só vai mostrar resultado se o tipo for zero, disponibilidade for zero, vvenda for zero, vtemporada for zero. Porém se tipo for diferente de zero e algum campo como: disponibilidade, vvenda ou vtempoarada for diferente de zero exibirá o resultado.

Comment: Tá, deixa eu ver se entendi.
Você quer que a consulta retorne (retornar, significa contar o cliente) se:
 - O tipo for igual a zero, disponibilidade zero, vanual zero e vtemporada zero;
- O tipo for DIFERENTE de zero e, ao menos um entre disponibilidade, vanual e vtemporada for diferente de zero.

É isso mesmo?

Comment: Isso mesmo, certinho

Comment: Com faço esta SQL?

Comment: Estou editando a postagem, um momento.

Comment: Deu erro amigo, a sql não roda!

Comment: Vou implementar meu texto acima para você acompanhar.

Comment: Viu minha implementaçãoa cima?

Comment: Tá, qual erro retorna?

Comment: Banco XML não abre!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37017/discussion-between-marcio-lordelo-and-gladison-neuza-perosini).

Comment: Por favor, vote no post caso tenha sido útil