# Exibir resultados SQL com filtros de campos expecíficos

Tags: php, sql

**Tenho o SQL:**

```
select id,disponibilidade,tipo from clientes where cliente = '$cliente' AND status = '2' AND tipo = '0' OR disponibilidade <> '0' OR vanual <> '0' OR vtemporada <> '0'
```

Tem que retornar registro se o campo **tipo** for igual a zero e se todos os campos **disponibilidade**, **vanual** e **vtemporada** forem zero. Mas... não retornara registro se o capo **tipo** for diferente de zero e também se algum dos campos como **disponibilidade**, **vanual** e **vtemporada** forem diferentes de zero.

Mas não estou conseguindo fazer!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como validar alguns campos em SQL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118230/como-validar-alguns-campos-em-sql)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Tenho uma QUERY que não exibe o que realmente preciso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118275/tenho-uma-query-que-n%c3%a3o-exibe-o-que-realmente-preciso)

Answer (score 0):

Tem que retornar registro se o campo tipo for igual a zero e se todos os campos disponibilidade, vanual e vtemporada forem zero.

```
tipo = 0
disponibilidade = 0
vanual = 0
vtemporada = 0
RETORNA OK
```

Mas... não retornara registro se o capo tipo for diferente de zero e também se algum dos campos como disponibilidade, vanual e vtemporada forem diferentes de zero.

```
SELECT id,disponibilidade,tipo 
  FROM clientes 
 WHERE cliente = '$cliente' 
   AND status = 2 
   AND tipo = 0
   AND disponibilidade = 0 
   AND vanual = 0 
   AND vtemporada = 0
```

Só não entendi o campo "status", mas, deve funcionar.