# Tenho uma QUERY que não exibe o que realmente preciso

Tags: php, sql, query

Minha Query:

```
    select id from clientes where cliente = '$cliente' AND status = '2' AND
(tipo <> '0' AND (disponibilidade <> '0'  OR vanual <> '0' OR vtemporada <> '0'))
```

Preciso que ela funcione da seguinte forma:

Que exiba algum registro se o campo **TIPO** for **diferente de ZERO** e que também pelo menos um dos campos: **disponibilidade**, **vanual** e **vtemporada** tenham algum valor diferente de zero.

Ou seja, para que exiba algum registro o campo **TIPO** é obrigatório ser diferente de **ZERO** e também algum dos campos **disponibilidade**, **vanual** e **vtemporada** tenham algum valor diferente de zero

Só que este SQL que montei não faz isso!

Aguardo ajuda por favor!

Comment: Já existe um tópico onde você perguntou a mesma coisa, haha. Tenta utilizar ele mesmo pra tentar resolver. Eu mesmo estou postando lá tentando te ajudar.

Segue link da outra postagem: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118230/como-validar-alguns-campos-em-sql/

Comment: Posta a estrutura da tabela.

Answer (score 2):

Modificando sua query, que acredito estar sendo atribuída a alguma variável antes de ser executada, tente da seguinte forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT id 
FROM clientes 
WHERE
cliente = $cliente 
AND status = 2
AND tipo <> 0 
AND (disponibilidade <> 0 OR vanual <> 0 OR vtemporada <> 0)"
```

Comment: Nada! Infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini Qual erro retorna?

Answer (score 1):

Depois de conversar, pelos chat, vi que o que você quer na verdade é:
Se o `tipo` for zero, já contabiliza. Caso o `tipo` seja diferente de zero, verifica se as outras informações são zero, e contabiliza.

Sendo isso mesmo o que você precisa, creio que a consulta a seguir retorne o esperado:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) as TOTAL_CLIENTES /*Conte 1 exibindo coluna como TOTAL_CLIENTES*/ 
    FROM 
    clientes /*Da tabela de clientes*/ 
    WHERE 
    (tipo = 0 ) /* Se o tipo for zero (só ai o cadastro já está incompleto)*/
    OR (/*OU*/
        tipo <> 0 /*Existe um tipo informado*/
        AND disponibilidade = 0 /*E a disponibilidade é zero*/
        AND vvenda = 0 /* E o vvenda é zero também*/
        AND vtemporada = 0 /* E o vtemporada também é zero, caracterizando um cliente que tem um tipo mas não tem nenhuma informação de valores*/
    )
```

Copiei a resposta do outro tópico criado.